# How can I get Yup form validator to recognize the react-select defaultValue and submit the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form, yup

I am attempting to render defaultValues in a react-select component.

var initValue = ['Chocolate', 'Strawberry', 'Vanilla];

The react-select components display with the correct default value.  However, my Yup validation doesn't recognize the default value (see image below) as a valid selection.

[image]

Therefore the form will not submit, although the fields are filled in.  Can someone advise how I can make my Yup validator recognize the defaultValue?  Please see working code version in my [github repo](https://github.com/tlockhart/react-form), which demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `value` instead of `defaultValue`.